# How to extract specific text from notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a log file that I need to extract specific data elements from.

Example text:

```
[22-12-20 21:16:04.521]   FROM LIVE   <$011B4B50:FleetCard_10:1,51.75,1,1,200001,Fleet No,5411,34319,TARJETA,,51.75,,3,0,1>
[22-12-20 21:16:04.553]   auth accepted tag=9812120450668474 device=V2
[22-12-20 21:16:40.185]   FROM LIVE   <02:PAYDONE=0000022851>
[22-12-20 21:17:20.677]     TO LIVE   <$011B4910:FleetCard_1:9812120450669349>
[22-12-20 21:17:21.270]   FROM LIVE   <$011B4910:FleetCard_10:1,49.48,1,1,200001,Fleet No,5237,34320,TARJETA,,49.48,,2,0,1>
[22-12-20 21:17:21.333]   auth accepted tag=9812120450669349 device=V1
[22-12-20 21:18:44.345]   FROM LIVE   <02:PAYDONE=0000022852>
[22-12-20 21:19:16.399]   FROM LIVE   <03:PAYDONE=0000022853>
[22-12-20 21:20:18.292]     TO LIVE   <$011B5150:FleetCard_1:9812120450669482>
[22-12-20 21:20:19.073]   FROM LIVE   <$011B5150:FleetCard_10:1,51.75,1,1,200001,Fleet No,2001,34321,TARJETA,,51.75,,3,0,1>
[22-12-20 21:20:19.167]   auth accepted tag=9812120450669482 device=V1
[22-12-20 21:21:53.536]     TO LIVE   <$011B4B50:FleetCard_1:9812120450668854>
[22-12-20 21:21:54.286]   FROM LIVE   <$011B4B50:FleetCard_10:1,51.75,1,1,200001,Fleet No,5418,34322,TARJETA,,51.75,,3,0,1>
[22-12-20 21:21:54.301]   auth accepted tag=9812120450668854 device=V2
[22-12-20 21:25:11.284]   FROM LIVE   <02:PAYDONE=0000022854>
[22-12-20 21:25:20.141]   FROM LIVE   <04:PAYDONE=0000022855>
```

I want to extract like below

```
Fleet No : 5411  tag :9812120450668474 
Fleet No:  5237  tag:9812120450669349
Fleet No : 2001  tag:9812120450669482
```

How to achieve this here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+?(Fleet No),(\d+).+?\R.+?(tag)=(\d+).+?(\R).+?`
- Replace with: `$1 : $2 $3 : $4$5`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(Fleet No)      # group 1, literally
,               # comma
(\d+)           # group 2, 1 or more digits
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\R              # any kind of linebreak
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(tag)           # group 3, literally
=               # equal sign
(\d+)           # group 4, 1 or more digits
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(\R)            # group 5, any kind of linebreak
.+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

**You have to manually delete the last 2 lines**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm extracting data from a large file, what I usually do is use TextPad.

1. I put my cursor at the beginning of the line I'm processing.
2. I start recording my macro that I can play multiple times.
3. I record my macro (with or without REGEX expressions) and reduce the line down to what data I need so that only that data is left on that line.  This usually gets my cursor to the beginning of the data I need, hit shift home, and then the delete key.  Then I search again, get my cursor to the end of my data, hit shift end, and then the delete key.  Now only my data is on that line.
4. After this, I hit home to move my cursor to the beginning of the current line.
5. I arrow down 1 line
6. I stop recording

It'll ask you whether you want to play to the end of the file or play it once.

Then I'll ask you if you want to save it.

Then I hit Control R for playback for each line you want to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool. This is CSV (Comma Separated Values) data that can easily be imported into a spreadsheet such as [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) [Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), as shown below. Then use the spreadsheet's functions to select appropriate data.

[image: Data as CSV file in Calc]

*N.B.* This is *not* a site to *write* code from scratch, though you may get help if you show your work.